# Фильтрация по выбранным checkbox

Tags: javascript

```js
const services = [{
    id: 1,
    Type: "Apple",
    Size: "L",
    Color: "Red"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Type: "Apple",
    Size: "S",
    Color: "Black"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Type: "Window",
    Size: "M",
    Color: "Black"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    Type: "Linux",
    Size: "M",
    Color: "White"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    Type: "Linux",
    Size: "S",
    Color: "Red"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    Type: "Windows",
    Size: "S",
    Color: "Red"
  },
]
```

```html
<form id="form">
  Выберите продукты:
  <div>
    <p>Type</p>
    <input id="apple" type="checkbox" name="Type-Apple">
    <label for="apple">Apple</label> <br>
    <input id="window" type="checkbox" name="Type-Window">
    <label for="window">Window</label> <br>
    <input id="linux" type="checkbox" name="Type-Linux">
    <label for="linux">Linux</label> <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Size</p>
    <input id="size-s" type="checkbox" name="Size-S">
    <label for="size-s">S</label> <br>
    <input id="size-m" type="checkbox" name="Size-M">
    <label for="size-m">M</label> <br>
    <input id="size-l" type="checkbox" name="Size-L">
    <label for="size-l">L</label> <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Color</p>
    <input id="color-black" type="checkbox" name="Color-Black">
    <label for="color-black">Black</label> <br>
    <input id="color-red" type="checkbox" name="Color-Red">
    <label for="color-red">Red</label> <br>
    <input id="color-white" type="checkbox" name="Color-White">
    <label for="color-white">White</label> <br>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<div>
  Выбранные продукты:
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Что нужно возвращать в случае если соответствующих массивов будет несколько? 2) Что нужно возвращать в случае если соответствующих массивов не будет?

Comment: 1) Если массивов несколько, возвращать все соответствующие массивы
2) Если не будет возвращать false

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можете попробовать такой вариант (лучше будет, если открыть на полный экран):

```js
const services = [{
    id: 1,
    Type: "Apple",
    Size: "L",
    Color: "Red"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Type: "Apple",
    Size: "S",
    Color: "Black"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Type: "Window",
    Size: "M",
    Color: "Black"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    Type: "Linux",
    Size: "M",
    Color: "White"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    Type: "Linux",
    Size: "S",
    Color: "Red"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    Type: "Windows",
    Size: "S",
    Color: "Red"
  },
]

const findServices = (filters) => {
  let answer = [...services];
  
  for (const filter in filters) {
    const filterSet = filters[filter];
   
    answer = answer.filter(
      item => filterSet.size === 0 ||  filterSet.has(item[filter])
    );
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#selected').innerHTML = answer.map(item => `<p>${item.Type} ${item.Size} ${item.Color}</p>`).join('');

  return answer;
}

const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#form [type="checkbox"]');

const filters = {
    Type: new Set(),
    Size: new Set(),
    Color: new Set(),
};

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    console.clear();
    
    const target = e.target;
    const [prop, value] = target.name.split('-');

    filters[prop][target.checked ? 'add' : 'delete']('' + value);

    findServices(filters);
  })
})

document.onload = findServices(filters);
```

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  width: 64%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <form id="form">
    Выберите продукты:
    <div>
      <p>Type</p>
      <input id="apple" type="checkbox" name="Type-Apple">
      <label for="apple">Apple</label> <br>
      <input id="window" type="checkbox" name="Type-Window">
      <label for="window">Window</label> <br>
      <input id="linux" type="checkbox" name="Type-Linux">
      <label for="linux">Linux</label> <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Size</p>
      <input id="size-s" type="checkbox" name="Size-S">
      <label for="size-s">S</label> <br>
      <input id="size-m" type="checkbox" name="Size-M">
      <label for="size-m">M</label> <br>
      <input id="size-l" type="checkbox" name="Size-L">
      <label for="size-l">L</label> <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Color</p>
      <input id="color-black" type="checkbox" name="Color-Black">
      <label for="color-black">Black</label> <br>
      <input id="color-red" type="checkbox" name="Color-Red">
      <label for="color-red">Red</label> <br>
      <input id="color-white" type="checkbox" name="Color-White">
      <label for="color-white">White</label> <br>
    </div>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div>
    Выбранные продукты:
    <div id="selected"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135040/discussion-on-answer-by-eziomercer----checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант:

1. Проходим исходный массив массивов
2. В каждом из них проходим искомый массив: все ли элементы есть
3. Если да, добавляем этот массив в результат

```js
const array1 = [
    ['apple', 'windows', 'linux'],
    ['iphone', 'android'],
    ['apple', 'windows']
];

function findArrayInArrayOfArrays (originalArrays, targetArray) {
  
  // Оставляем в новом массиве только те массивы, в которых есть искомые значения
  const resultArray = originalArrays.filter( originalArray => {
    
    // Проверяем, что все искомые значения есть в массиве
    return targetArray.reduce( (isValid, targetValue) => {
      if ( isValid === true && originalArray.includes(targetValue) ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }, true);
  });
  
  // По условиям задачи разные варианты того, что возвращает функция
  if ( resultArray.length === 0 ) return false;
  if ( resultArray.length === 1 ) return resultArray[0];
  return resultArray;
}

console.log( findArrayInArrayOfArrays (array1, ['apple', 'linux']) ) // Одно совпадение: ['apple', 'windows', 'linux']
console.log( findArrayInArrayOfArrays (array1, ['apple', 'linux', 10]) ) // Нет совпадений
console.log( findArrayInArrayOfArrays (array1, ['apple']) ) // Более одного совпадения
```